# Swift - JSON decoding

Tags: json, swift, generics

I have a JSON response from an api call. The problem is I get different JSON responses depending on whether the user has entered the correct credentials or not. My question is how do I read and decode these responses to a useable struct and what is the best way to go about decoding these different responses. one thing I noticed is both response have a common "isSuccess" that may be useful. I have little to no experience with swift or reading JSON so this is all a learning experience for me.

This is the response for successful login

```
{"result":{"login":{"isAuthorized":true,"isEmpty":false,"userName":{"isEmpty":false,"name":{"firstName":"Jason","lastName":"Test","displayName":"Test, Jason","isEmpty":false,"fullName":"Jason Test"},"canDelete":false,"id":5793,"canModify":false},"username":"test@testable.com"},"parameters":{"isEmpty":false,"keep_logged_in_indicator":false,"username":"test@testable.com"}},"isAuthorized":true,"version":{"major":"2021","minor":"004","fix":"04","display":"2021.004.04","isEmpty":false},"isSystemDown":false,"timestamp":"2021-07-28T02:47:33Z","isSuccess":true}
```

This is the response for failure

```
{"isAuthorized":true,"version":{"major":"2021","minor":"004","fix":"04","display":"2021.004.04","isEmpty":false},"isSystemDown":false,"errors":[{"password":"Unable to login as 'test@testable.com'"}],"timestamp":"2021-07-28T02:47:05Z","isSuccess":false}
```

This is the code I have written for my api calls

```
func request<T: Decodable>(endPoint: EndPoint, method: Method, parameters: [String: Any]? = nil, completion: @escaping(Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        // Creates a urlRequest
        guard let request = createRequest(endPoint: endPoint, method: method, parameters: parameters) else {
            completion(.failure(AppError.invalidUrl))
            return
        }
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            var results: Result<Data, Error>?
            
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                completion(.failure(AppError.badStatusCode))
                return
            }
            
            if let response = response {
                
                // Gets the JSESSIONID
                let cookieName = "JSESSIONID"
                if let cookie = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies?.first(where: { $0.name == cookieName })  {
                    debugPrint("\(cookieName): \(cookie.value)")
                }
               
                print(response)
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                results = .success(data)
                
                // Converts data to readable String
                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "unable to convert to readable String"
                print("Server Response: \(responseString.description)")
 
            } else if let error = error {
                results = .failure(error)
                print("Server Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.handleResponse(result: results, completion: completion)
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
    

    private func handleResponse<T: Decodable>(result: Result<Data, Error>?, completion: (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let result = result else {
            completion(.failure(AppError.unknownError))
            return
        }
        
        switch result {
        
            case .success(let data):
                
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print("Server JsonObject response: \(json)")
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(AppError.errorDecoding))
                }
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // Decodes that json data
                do {
 
                } catch {
                    
                }
                
                
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
```

Im mostly interesting in being able to display the json error that occurs when credentials are incorrect. The deadline for my project Is slowing approaching and any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where does a guy named createRequest come from?  method?  parameters?  What are they and where do they come from?

Comment: I'd suggest reading about Codable as opposed to JSONSerialization -- lots of tutorials available on the web. Also, check out the website app.quicktype.io

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swift's `Result` type to differentiate a successful result from a failed result.

The `Result` type is not decodable by default so you will need to [write a custom decoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) like this:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let result: Swift.Result<Result, Errors>

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isSuccess
        case errors
        case result
    }

    struct Result: Codable {
        let login: Login

        struct Login: Codable {
            let isAuthorized: Bool
        }
    }

    struct Errors: Error {
        let contents: [[String: String]]
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isSuccess) {
            result = .success(try container.decode(Result.self, forKey: .result))
        } else {
            result = .failure(
                Errors(contents: try container.decode([[String: String]].self, forKey: .errors))
            )
        }
    }
}
```